# I'm using parrot os. My realtek rtw8822ce stays connected but after every 5 min. It stops working

Tags: networking, wifi, network-interface, wlan, parrotsec

I'm using parrot os. My realtek rtw8822ce stays connected but after every 5 min. It stops working. Reconnecting again makes the wifi work again. Firstly I had this problem. Then I installed some driver from github: `https://github.com/juanro49/rtl88x2ce-dkms`. It solved the problem of internet not working but it induced a new issue of being unstable net. Which was painful during video calls cause after 5 mins it stops working and got fixed automatically after 20 sec. The only difference is now I have to manually reconnect after the network error to reestablish the net. Then I installed another driver from here `https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88` and everything was smooth.But one day I fell asleep when the laptop battery became extremely low and the laptop turned off. After booting it after that now I have this internet not working after every 5 min.
I'm too frustrated with this problem.
Tried many solutions. But of no help.

```
└──╼ $lsmod | grep 88
rtw_8822ce             16384  0
rtw_8822c             491520  1 rtw_8822ce
rtw_pci                28672  1 rtw_8822ce
rtw_core              245760  2 rtw_8822c,rtw_pci
rtl88x2ce            3067904  0
cfg80211             1024000  4 wl,rtl88x2ce,rtw_core,mac80211
md_mod                188416  6 raid1,raid10,raid0,linear,raid456,multipath
raid6_pq              122880  4 async_pq,btrfs,raid456,async_raid6_recov
drm                   634880  20 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper,ttm,nouveau
```

Comment: https://github.com/juanro49/rtl88x2ce-dkms

Comment: I've this driver installed. But my modprobe is not loading this driver

Comment: First of all, you need to include what you've already tried in your question. Nobody wants to spend the time to ask you about every single possibility. Second, you want to include logs of the time when the issue occurs. Third, please add the output of `lsmod | grep 88` to your question for us to be  able to see that the driver in fact is not loaded

Comment: I have updated the question properly

Comment: Thanks for at least reacting to one of the three asked questions. As a reminder, you might want to look into the syslog and kernel log via `journalctl -f` and `dmesg -wH` and record what error comes up when the issue occurs. Usually logs contain valuable information about an error. Once a problem is identified, it makes it **much** easier to find a solution. You might want to add what you've already tried to resolve the issue.

Comment: Okay when the error occurs next time.
I'll copy pasted the logs also.

Comment: It would be preferable if you would first try to read and understand the logs, then identify the part which could correlate with your issue and look it up using a search engine of your choice. If you've successfully identified a related error message and you can't find any information about it on the internet, you could ask others, for example here on SU.